# How do you retrieve a value from a map that has a pair as a key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

So lets say I have: `map<pair<int, MyEnum>, string> myMap;`

and I add a key value: `myMap[make_pair(1, MyEnum::first)] = "something";`

how can I retrieve the value "something"

so if the map was `map<int, string>` and I had `myMap[1] = "something";`

i would say `string s = myMap[1]`

Comment: Why is the key a pair ? Cannot you use the pair on the other side ? Keep key as 1 and use **MyEnum::first and "something"** as the data.

Comment: You need the key to find something by key. If you don't want to have to supply the value of the enum to look something up, it shouldn't be part of the key. See my comment to Nawaz's answer. It looks like you really want `map< int, pair< MyEnum, string > >`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the same way,

```
std::cout << myMap[make_pair(1, MyEnum::first)] << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
something
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Exactly. If the OP wants to look up by `int`, he should have made `int` the key and made the *value* `pair<MyEnum, string>`. The key is basically "whatever you want to give to find a value". The value is "whatever you want to find by key". If you want to find the enum, rather than finding *by* the enum, it should be part of the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = myMap[make_pair(1, MyEnum::first)];
```